# JQuery errors with Wordpress site after deleting and setting up directories

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I wanted to change the location of my Wordpress website from a subdirectory to the root. I made a back-up of my files and my database. But I made a mistake by moving my site to the root. First, I moved the site in Filezilla and after that I changed the URL in wordpress. I was dealing with a 500 error, so my hosting company advised me to restore everything to what is was before.

Now my site gives 22 Jquery errors and I can't adjust anything in wp-admin anymore.

These are my errors I'm dealing with:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
jquery-migrate.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at query-migrate.min.js:2
jquery.flexslider-min.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js:43 at jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js:45
jquery.fancybox.js:2020 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at jquery.fancybox.js:2020
enter code here jquery.elevatezoom.js:1790 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at jquery.elevatezoom.js:1790
    jquery.dotdotdot.min.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at jquery.dotdotdot.min.js:13
    jquery.gridrotator.js:756 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at jquery.gridrotator.js:756
    bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    jquery.colorbox.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    shortcodes.js:31 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at shortcodes.js:31
    parallax.js:154 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at parallax.js:154
    uikit.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: UIkit requires jQuery
        at uikit.min.js:3
        at uikit.min.js:3
    main.js:782 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at main.js:782
    (index):184 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at (index):184
    scripts.js:481 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at scripts.js:481
    jquery.sliderPro.js:1450 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at jquery.sliderPro.js:1450
    post-favorite.js:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at post-favorite.js:29
    datepicker.min.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    js_composer_front.min.js?ver=5.1.1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at getSizeName (js_composer_front.min.js?ver=5.1.1:1)
        at js_composer_front.min.js?ver=5.1.1:1
    owl.carousel.min.js:47 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at owl.carousel.min.js:47
    tb.carousel.js:209 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at tb.carousel.js:209
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It complains about jQuery is not being loaded. So my initial thought would be a caching issue. It might be still looking at old location.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I fix that problem? You're right my jQuery isn't being loaded cause none of my jQuery is working.

Comment: The problem is at this website: www.wienekeprinsen.nl/v2

Comment: This is a very odd issue. I can see that jQuery is loaded but looks like something in it causing the problem. Did you try to get latest one and replace it. that actually may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the issue. the jquery seems to be corrupted when you move folders around. On the left below image is original jquery.1.12.4 and the one on the right is what you have.

[image]

[image]